# Error de variables en python en visual code

Tags: python, django

hola buenas noches estoy haciendo un proyectito en python usando el editor de codigo python
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

bueno al compilar el programa la verdad no me permite seguir por haí estuve checando y varios forum me dice que es por que no hago referencia hacia la carpeta de python ya lo hice y bueno el porblema sigue
alguien podria ayudarme de antemanos muchas gracias

estoy usando python 3.8

- considero que mi error seria en mi programa no tanto en mi direccion de la carperta de python

Comment: ¿Seguro que las variables que usas están definidas?

Comment: Intenta imports relativos, pues veo que el script que te da problema está en el mismo paquete que el módulo que importas. Es decir, pon `from .models import *`